# NGINX SSL certificate permission SSL error :0200100D:system

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

Getting following error in NGINX server, Using LetsEncrypts free SSL Certificate.

2016/06/23 19:53:13 [warn] 5013#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

2016/06/23 19:53:13 [emerg] 5013#0: BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/abc/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/abc/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)

Answer (score 16):

If your chmod and chown is all correct on the file, this is probably because you copied a file into a folder - maybe home folder (say) - then mv'd the file into position for NGINX.  SeLinux remembers the original file creation location and applies the rights wherever the file is mv'd to - to reset the SeLinux permissions to the current location/file permissions use

`restorecon filename`

This usually sorts it

Comment: This fixed it for me. The crt and key files were generated in a user folder and despite changing the ownership and running nginx as root, the file was giving permission denied. Running restorecon fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Both problems have one root cause.

1. This error usually happens, when you try to start nginx with non-root user. You could try to start as root or under sudo.
2. Looks like you have permission on your pem file, which not allow nginx to read it when you start it from non-root user, you could try to change file permission or start nginx as root or under sudo.

Comment: I have the same though than @Alexander T, it seems that your nginx was started with no root rights, but your certificate is probably owned by root (to check permission and owner of your certificate `ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc/fullchain.pem`)

Comment: Foolishly forgot to run `service nginx restart` as root. sudo-ing it solved it for me

Answer (score 9):

Hello I also had the same similar issue.

```
setenforce 0
```

It was solved this way.

Comment: This can impact your entire system security, I would recommend setting SELinux properly instead of deactivating it.

Comment: I think this answer could be an OK answer if it explains what it's doing, and why it's not recommended.

Answer (score 7):

If you run `nginx` worker process from www-data user, it needs just set rights on `/etc/letsencrypt/` folder:

```sh
chown -R www-data:www-data /etc/letsencrypt/
chmod -R 755 /etc/letsencrypt/
```

It should works

Comment: After hours of debugging, I was able to fix it with this! :) The problem was, I had generated the certificate as root user inside my docker container and hence had the permission issue. Used this to update the permissions within my container and then restarted docker service on host.

Answer (score 2):

In my case(Oracle Linux 8), similar issue resolved after changing contexts of *.pem* files.

```
$ chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t *.pem
```

Comment: This command was really helpful to fix my issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it by copying the files to the `/etc/ssl/certs/` folder and changing the path in `nginx.conf`